# How to exit from qnadialog and to continue with other luis intent

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

i have created a bot using luis and qnamaker dialog. in my questions is a part of the code of LuisDialog.cs . During the conversations if user make a questions that is part of qna intent ( the bot jumb to QnADialog) , but i want to pass to other intent when user make another questions to the bot .

LuisDialog.cs here is my code updated with other intent . I want to quit from qnadialog when user type a questions that correspond to test intent for example

```
   using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
  using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models;
   using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
   using MultiDialogsBot.Dialogs;
    using System.Threading;

  namespace MultiDialogsBot
  {

[LuisModel("xxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyyyyy")]
[Serializable]
public class LuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    private object activity;


    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }


    [LuisIntent("None")]
    [LuisIntent("")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        string message = $"Désolé je n'ai pas compris '{result.Query}'. Veuillez formuler votre question";

        await context.PostAsync(message);

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);


    }

    [LuisIntent("test")]

    public async Task test(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("nous testons");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);

    }



    [LuisIntent("qna")]
    public async Task qna(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {
        var msg = await activity;

        //  await context.Forward(new QnADialog(), ResumeAfterOptionDialog, msg, CancellationToken.None);
        context.Call(new QnADialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);

    }

    public async Task ResumeAfterOptionDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var messageHandled = await result;
        if (messageHandled != null)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Désolé je n'ai pas compris");
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do? It's not clear

Comment: i have created a bot using luis and qnamaker dialog. in my questions is a part of the code of LuisDialog.cs . During the conversations if user make a questions that is part of qna intent ( the bot jumb to QnADialog) , but i want to pass to other intent when user make another questions to the bot ( i hope i was more clear now )

Comment: Ok, can you add all your LuisDialog.cs please? To be clear: QnA should get the intent, if it is not in your QnA KB you want a fallback?

Comment: @NicolasR i have updated my code

Comment: I still don't understand the way you try to implement it. If you want to try to match LUIS intent when your QnA doesn't have an answer, you should not use LUIS before QnA but LUIS after QnA

Comment: you mean i cannot use a qnamaker inside an intent ?

Comment: The power of QnADialog is to automatically handle the message, try to find an answer, etc. Here you add a layer with LUIS where you will have to teach your LUIS Model to try to detect if it looks like something that could be answered by your QnADialog.
I think it should be on the contrary: you give your text to your QnADialog directly, and handle the case where this dialog doesn't have an answer, and in that case call your LUIS Dialog to go into your specific intents that are not part of the QnADialog

Comment: And if you ask yourself how it can be done, this sample is a good one around your case: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/QnAMaker/QnABotWithOverrides/Dialogs/QnADialogWithOverrides.cs
I will try to make an answer based on what I said previously

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat the user input inside your QnA database first, your should change your logic described in your question and set an overridden QnADialog that will get your user input first, and when there is no reply, call a LuisDialog to try to handle the case with 1 or several interesting intents.

You can check [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Library/QnAMaker/QnAMakerDialog.cs) how the `QnAMakerDialog` is made. You will see that you probably need to rewrite the class to change the `MessageReceivedAsync` method to avoid the reply from the QnAMakerDialog here:

```
if (sendDefaultMessageAndWait)
{
    // The following line should be removed if you don't want that the QnADialog replies if no answer found
    await context.PostAsync(qnaMakerResults.ServiceCfg.DefaultMessage);
    await this.DefaultWaitNextMessageAsync(context, message, qnaMakerResults);
}
```

Your QnAOverriddenDialog must be called from where your LuisDialog was called previously (from your MessageController I guess, as I don't have the details of your implementation).

And your LuisDialog will look like the following:

```
[LuisModel("xxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyyyyy")]
[Serializable]
public class LuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    [LuisIntent("None")]
    [LuisIntent("")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        string message = $"Désolé je n'ai pas compris '{result.Query}'. Veuillez formuler votre question";

        await context.PostAsync(message);    
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
    }

    [LuisIntent("test")]
    public async Task test(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("nous testons");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    [LuisIntent("yourOtherIntent1")]
    public async Task OtherIntent1(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("fallback 1");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    [LuisIntent("yourOtherIntent2")]
    public async Task OtherIntent1(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("fallback 2");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    public async Task ResumeAfterOptionDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var messageHandled = await result;
        if (messageHandled != null)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Désolé je n'ai pas compris");
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Soory ...i'm beginner and i very confused. I updated my code with QnAMakerDialog  as in example ( with other class related ) so all the library ...but without result. Is it possible to found an example , a code that use both luis and qnamaker . In luis is you type hi - is called intent greetings  , if you type test  - is called test intent , if you type mobile ( i want to call qnadialog) , and after this questions if i type again hi , i want to re call greetings intent. My problem is that i enter in a loop inside qnamaker and i cannot exit from it. :( Thank you for your time again...

Comment: There are some examples of code where LUIS is called first, and when the developer has no matching intent, QnAMakerDialog is called to try to provide an answer. I'm still not sure of what is your final business case and this would change the way you are developing the solution. Could you add more use cases to your question, telling the kind of sentence is typed in entry and what should be the reply and where does it comes from (LUIS or QnA) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[LuisIntent("qna")]
public async Task qna(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
{
    var msg = await activity;
    await context.Forward(new QnADialog(), ResumeAfterQnA, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);
    await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
}

private async Task ResumeAfterQnA(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            context.Done<object>(null);
        }

    private async Task ShowLuisResult(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"You have reached {result.Intents[0].Intent}. You said: {result.Query}");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
```